# What is actually happening inside List.nth in SML?

Tags: functional-programming, sml

Could somebody help me understand List.nth in SML?

It outputs a specified element from the list.
a)

```
List.nth ([7,3,6,1],0);
val it = 7 : int
```

b)

```
List.nth ([7,3,6,1],1);
val it = 3 : int
```

For example:

1. Implementation of **map** function using recursion would be:

fun map _ nil = nil
| map f (a::b) = (f a) :: (map f b);

2. Implementation of **foldr** function using recursion would be:

fun foldr _ c nil = c
| foldr f c (a::b) = f(a, foldr f c b);

Likewise, what is actually happening inside List.nth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple implementation of `List.nth` would be something like the following, using pattern-matching, and the `option` type to handle out of bounds errors.

```
fun nth([], _) = NONE
  | nth(x::_, 0) = SOME x
  | nth(x::xs, i) = nth(xs, i - 1)
```

- It doesn't matter what index we're looking for in an empty list. It's not there.
- If the index is `0`, return the first element in the list. It doesn't matter what the rest of the list is.
- Otherwise, call `nth` on the rest of the list and decrease the index by 1.

So if we call `nth([3, 7, 4, 1, 8], 3)` the recursion looks like:

```
nth([3, 7, 4, 1, 8], 3)
nth([7, 4, 1, 8], 2)
nth([4, 1, 8], 1)
nth([1, 8], 0)
SOME 1
```

Comment: Wow, your explanation of how the recursion looks like is really helpful! Thanks a ton!!

Comment: I solved it like this: 

`fun get_nth (a::b, n) =
    if n = 1
        then a
         else get_ntha(b, n-1);
    
val answer = get_nth([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]], 2);`
Thankyou!

Comment: Glad I could help! If you feel this and/or the other answer works for you, please feel free to accept them.

Comment: Be careful, because your function's pattern-matching isn't exhaustive: it doesn't handle an empty list.

Comment: Also, could you teach me how does the recursion look like for let-val-in-end case? I have a hard time understanding the procession ie the breakdown of the loop.

Here is the question :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69654326/how-does-recursion-looks-like-for-let-in-end-in-sml

Answer (score 0):

`nth (l, i)` returns the `i`(th) element of the list `l`, counting from 0. In other words it's accessing the element in `l` by index `i`.

In example "a" `List.nth([7,3,6,1], 0)` returns the `i`(th) element in `l` which is `7`

In example "b" `List.nth([7,3,6,1], 1)` returns the `i`(th) element in `l` which is `3`

Comment: Thankyou for reply! I understand that, ie it takes out elements pointed by position. However here, I am trying to figure out the function inside it. How does it does it? I could figureout the recursive function for List.map and List.foldr (like mentioned above) but couldnt find out for List.nth

Comment: Looking at some code for `nth` online looks like it doesn't take out elements but has an inner function that de-structures the list into head and tail elements and maintains a counter on each "iteration". When that counter is `0` it returns the current head of the list. http://smlnj-gforge.cs.uchicago.edu/scm/viewvc.php/sml/trunk/system/Basis/Implementation/list.sml?view=markup&root=smlnj